# How to horizontally center inner div inside an outer div?

Tags: javascript, html, centering

I need to center a div horizontally inside another div

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="outer" class="outerDiv">
    <div id="inner" class="innerDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css :

```
.outerDiv {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}

.innerDiv {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue; 
    // what to add here ?
}
```

You may try it: http://jsfiddle.net/nggSG/

**How may I horizontally center the blue div inside the red div ?**

Comment: if you also want to center it verticallly it's a little harder... if you want i post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.innerDiv {
    margin: auto;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Centers div horizontally

Answer (score 2):

like this :

```
.innerDiv {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    margin : 0 auto;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

```
.outerDiv {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;

    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

.innerDiv {
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    top: 25px; left: 25px;

    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you subtract the width and height of the outer div from the inner div and divide by 2, you know how much you need to move over the inner div. Also, the outer div *must* be `position: relative` and the inner div *must* be `position: absolute`.

If you need a more dynamic centering solution, I've been using Midway.js by Shipp Co (http://shipp.co/midway). Hope this helped!

EDIT: jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5A9sq

Comment: are you serious ? Centering vertically can indeed sometimes be a bit challenging, but horizontal centering can be achieved quite easily. Your solution is non-flexible and hard to maintain, although it would indeed do the job for this specific fiddle. And the link you provide is about centering an absolute positioned element, which was not the case until you did in your answer

Comment: Wow dude, relax. Thanks for the -1, but the OP already selected an answer, thereby rendering mine ineffective. Everyone is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="outer" class="outerDiv">
    <div id="inner" class="innerDiv">
      Inner div (centered)
    </div>
</div>
```

simple css

```
    .outerDiv{
        width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .innerDiv{
        width:50%;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: yellow;
        color: black;
    }
```